# "undefined reference to" linux with make libnl

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, hyperlink, package

I am trying to build a project in Linux and I have many errors of this style:
**/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libnl-route-3.so: undefined reference to `nlmsg_hdr@libnl_3'**.
I have looked at many of the similar threads available but none have worked for me. I have libnl-3-dev and libnl-genl-3-dev installed, but when executing the "make" command I have like 20 erros similar to the above with different references but the same "libnl-route-3.so".

I'm new to Makefiles, I have tried to modified it to see if the result changed, but there have not been improvements.
I leave below the Makefile, it is quite long, and execution shows the errors when it reaches the "server" part.
In order to build, I first "qmake" and then "make", any help is appreciated. It seems that libnl3 package is in /usr/include/libnl3/netlink, I think that the problem is that it is not linked correctly but I have not been able to do it.

```
MAKEFILE      = Makefile

first: make_first
QMAKE         = /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
COPY          = cp -f
COPY_FILE     = cp -f
COPY_DIR      = cp -f -R
INSTALL_FILE  = install -m 644 -p
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
INSTALL_DIR   = cp -f -R
QINSTALL      = /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -install qinstall
QINSTALL_PROGRAM = /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -install qinstall -exe
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
TAR           = tar -cf
COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
DISTNAME      = ost1.0.0
DISTDIR = /home/pi/Desktop/CAF/Ostinato/ostinato_master/.tmp/ost1.0.0
SUBTARGETS    =  \
        client \
        server \
        sub-common-ostproto-pro \
        sub-common-ostprotogui-pro \
        sub-rpc-pbrpc-pro \
        sub-extra



server-qmake_all: sub-common-ostproto-pro-qmake_all sub-rpc-pbrpc-pro-qmake_all FORCE
    @test -d server/ || mkdir -p server/
    cd server/ && $(QMAKE) -o Makefile.drone /home/pi/Desktop/CAF/Ostinato/ostinato_master/server/drone.pro
    cd server/ && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.drone qmake_all
server: sub-common-ostproto-pro \
        sub-rpc-pbrpc-pro FORCE
    @test -d server/ || mkdir -p server/
    cd server/ && ( test -e Makefile.drone || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile.drone /home/pi/Desktop/CAF/Ostinato/ostinato_master/server/drone.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.drone
server-make_first: sub-common-ostproto-pro-make_first sub-rpc-pbrpc-pro-make_first FORCE
    @test -d server/ || mkdir -p server/
    cd server/ && ( test -e Makefile.drone || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile.drone /home/pi/Desktop/CAF/Ostinato/ostinato_master/server/drone.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.drone 
server-all: sub-common-ostproto-pro-all sub-rpc-pbrpc-pro-all FORCE
    @test -d server/ || mkdir -p server/
    cd server/ && ( test -e Makefile.drone || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile.drone /home/pi/Desktop/CAF/Ostinato/ostinato_master/server/drone.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.drone all
server-clean: sub-common-ostproto-pro-clean sub-rpc-pbrpc-pro-clean FORCE
    @test -d server/ || mkdir -p server/
    cd server/ && ( test -e Makefile.drone || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile.drone /home/pi/Desktop/CAF/Ostinato/ostinato_master/server/drone.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.drone clean
server-distclean: sub-common-ostproto-pro-distclean sub-rpc-pbrpc-pro-distclean FORCE
    @test -d server/ || mkdir -p server/
    cd server/ && ( test -e Makefile.drone || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile.drone /home/pi/Desktop/CAF/Ostinato/ostinato_master/server/drone.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.drone distclean
server-install_subtargets: sub-common-ostproto-pro-install_subtargets sub-rpc-pbrpc-pro-install_subtargets FORCE
    @test -d server/ || mkdir -p server/
    cd server/ && ( test -e Makefile.drone || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile.drone /home/pi/Desktop/CAF/Ostinato/ostinato_master/server/drone.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.drone install
server-uninstall_subtargets: sub-common-ostproto-pro-uninstall_subtargets sub-rpc-pbrpc-pro-uninstall_subtargets FORCE
    @test -d server/ || mkdir -p server/
    cd server/ && ( test -e Makefile.drone || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile.drone /home/pi/Desktop/CAF/Ostinato/ostinato_master/server/drone.pro ) && $(MAKE) 
server-distdir: FORCE
    @test -d server/ || mkdir -p server/
    cd server/ && ( test -e Makefile.drone || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile.drone /home/pi/Desktop/CAF/Ostinato/ostinato_master/server/drone.pro ) && $(MAKE) -e -f Makefile.drone distdir DISTDIR=$(DISTDIR)/server
```

The command output:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Desktop/CAF/Ostinato/ostinato_master/server'
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o drone devicemanager.o device.o emuldevice.o drone_main.o drone.o portmanager.o abstractport.o pcapport.o pcapsession.o pcaptransmitter.o pcaprxstats.o pcaptxstats.o pcaptxthread.o bsdhostdevice.o bsdport.o linuxhostdevice.o linuxport.o params.o winhostdevice.o winpcapport.o myservice.o pcapextra.o packetbuffer.o version.o moc_drone.o moc_pcaptransmitter.o moc_myservice.o   -lpcap -L../common -lostproto -L../rpc -lpbrpc -lnl-3 -lnl-route-3 -lm -lprotobuf -lQt5Network -lQt5Script -lQt5Xml -lQt5Core -lpthread -latomic 
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libnl-route-3.so: undefined reference to `nl_ticks2us@libnl_3'
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libnl-route-3.so: undefined reference to `nla_parse_nested@libnl_3'
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libnl-route-3.so: undefined reference to `nla_get_u32@libnl_3'
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libnl-route-3.so: undefined reference to `nl_cache_pickup@libnl_3'
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libnl-route-3.so: undefined reference to `nl_cache_mngt_register@libnl_3'
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libnl-route-3.so: undefined reference to `nl_addr_get_prefixlen@libnl_3'
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libnl-route-3.so: undefined reference to `__type2str@libnl_3'
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libnl-route-3.so: undefined reference to `nl_cache_alloc_and_fill@libnl_3'
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libnl-route-3.so: undefined reference to `nl_us2ticks@libnl_3'
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libnl-route-3.so: undefined reference to `nl_geterror@libnl_3'
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libnl-route-3.so: undefined reference to `nla_get_string@libnl_3'
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libnl-route-3.so: undefined reference to `nl_str2af@libnl_3'
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libnl-route-3.so: undefined reference to `nl_addr_build@libnl_3'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile.drone:220: drone] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/CAF/Ostinato/ostinato_master/server'
make: *** [Makefile:79: server-make_first] Error 2
```

Comment: there's a lot of code there, please try to provide a [mre], the resulting compiler command would probably be more helpful than the full makefile

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/libnl-route-3.so` for sure does not come from the distribution and most likely is mismatched with the ones provided in system packages. You can try to remove that library and let it take the system library instead.

Comment: Thanks, I removed it and now works.